# Mockito - Using "when" on "any" object of that kind

Tags: java, junit, mockito, matcher

I am trying to write a test where I want to make a function return a mock object anytime that function is called with any instance of that class.

For ex -

```
class A {
     Object fun(){

      }
}
I'm trying something like this - 
@Test
void sanTest(){
   Object mock;
   when(any(A.class).fun()).thenReturn(mock);
 }
```

What's the correct way to do this ? Does Mockito have this kind of functionality ?
The reason I have to write this is that I'm writing Junit for another class B where a new instance of "A" is created to call fun.

```
 class B {

       void f2(){
          Object o = new A().fun();
            -----
      }

}
```

Comment: Short answer: not possible with Mockito. Use PowerMockito instead.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for responding. Is power mockito preferred these days over mockito or both have different usecases

Comment: Honestly, I've never used PowerMockito. But Mockito probably has a very good reason for not having this functionality. Probably because it actually is a very weird requirement, usually solved by refactoring the code itself.